# Laravel Sail's up command logs and doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-sail

Laravel Sail project made using default command mentioned in docs, when I run `./vendor/bin/sail up` It logs this over and over:

```
projectname-meilisearch-1   | [2022-05-04T18:01:14Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 127.0.0.1 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Wget" 0.000140
projectname-mailhog-1       | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's already running. Now you can access via http://localhost